# 'The Transaction Log for database is full due to 'Active Transaction' - Unable to Backup, Enlarge, Truncate, or Shrink

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I have a SQL Server database that keeps giving me the following error:

> Msg 9002, Level 17, State 4, Line 30
>   The transaction log for database 'DSC_DW_Summary' is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'.

I can see that the log file is at 100% of "Log Space Used" despite my using Simple Recovery and 1 minute recovery time.  When I try do any of the following (suggested online as potential solutions) I get the error listed above.

- Increase the MaxSize of the log file
- Backup the database
- Shrink the database

I also don't see any running transactions when I run:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_database_transactions
```

or:

```
DBCC OPENTRAN
```

Which gives me the result:

> No active open transactions.
>   DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

So I'm baffled.  Somehow I'm being prevented from resolving the issue because of an "Active Transaction" but I can't find any active transactions.

Comment: OT - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). But simple recovery model and "1 minute recovery time" are inconsistent. Simple means you can recover only to the last backup. Highly doubtful you are taking full backups once every minute.

Comment: What would you do differently @SMor?  Set recovery time to weekly?

Answer (score 3):

Start with checking what is preventing your log reuse:

`SELECT [name], [log_reuse_wait_desc]
    FROM [sys].[databases];`

Then also issue a CHECKPOINT to try and flush the log